# UITextField text is removed after showing pop up

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm facing the following issue: I have several UITextFields in my view, one of them (Expiry date) has a button on it which opens a pop up with UIDatePicker. After getting back I see that my textfields are empty. 
Find the screen recording attached. 
Also, here's a piece of code which I use:

```
func showDatePickerPopUp() {
    let dateVC = NavigationHelper.shared.getViewController("datePickerID") as! DatePickerPopUpViewController
    dateVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(dateVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

And then I call this method from button action:

```
@IBAction func expiryDateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showDatePickerPopUp()
}
```

And when expiry date becomes first responder:

```
if textField == cardNumberTextField {
    nameOnCardTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
} else if textField == nameOnCardTextField {
    expiryDateTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    showDatePickerPopUp()
}
```

Here's how it works: [Screen Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQhB9.gif)

How can I solve this issue?

Update:
Here's the "Done" button action code:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/yyyy"
   let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
   let vc = NavigationHelper.shared.getViewController("changeCard") as!    ChangeCardViewController
   vc.expiryDate = dateString
   present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: is there any code to clear UITextField text in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Comment: @iVarun, no
The only thing I do with UITextFields text, is the following: 
`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

expiryDateTextField.text = expiryDate`

But even when I comment this line, it works the same way(

Comment: What you are doing on click Done button of `DatePickerPopUpViewController` ?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint on the any other `textField` to see when it gets modified after clicking on `DONE`?

Comment: @iVarun, wait a minute, I will paste it in my question as Update

Comment: @EmmaVagradyan : From the GIF it seems you are re-initializing the controller and thus your whole data is lost. yes, now we can see that you are re-initializing on `doneButtonTapped `. Instead dismiss the controller and pass data back using `Closure` or `Delegate` not setting the expiryDate

Comment: Also I would suggest instead of using new popupController for picker, you should add `datePicker` as the `inputView` to `expiryDateTextField ` and this will help you manage the datePicked in same controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dismiss your `ChangeCardViewController` on action of done button. As you are presenting controller again it will reload all the views of `ChangeCardViewController`. Write below code in `doneButtonTapped`:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```